# Set local bind address for client socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have multiple NIC (Network interfaces) installed on a server. Is it possible for me to set the default local bind address for existing client sockets in JAVA?

It is possible to do it programmatically through the method:

```
new Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

Problem is that I don't have access to SocketFactory so I cannot specify localAddr value.

Comment: Why? TCP will sort that out when you connect the socket. You don't have to do IP routing yourself.

Comment: You show the `Socket` constructor for setting the local address and they say you don't have access to a `SocketFactory`. `SocketFactory` doesn't appear to be required for that method, so where is your problem?

Comment: @user2689005 I see you are using a library. By the time any library returns you a connected socket, or something wrapped around it, it is already too late to bind it, as it is already bound. I ask again. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the abstract [`SocketFactory.createSocket()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29) method you speak of in your question, points to this constructor that offers what you need;

```
 public Socket.Socket(InetAddress address,
     int port,
     InetAddress localAddr,
     int localPort)
         throws IOException
```

[Docs found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29)

---

If you need to change the localAddress of an existing socket you should use the [`bind(SocketAddress bindpoint)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) method, however that will throw an `IOException` if the socket is already bound.

You should pass an [`InetSocketAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) to that method as [`SocketAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketAddress.html) is abstract.

---

If your having trouble finding the internal IP addresses of each of your interfaces [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html) guide explains how to retrieve a collection of them.